# Linking error with openssl-1.1.0c

Tags: static, linker, openssl

I'm using Ubuntu 16.10 and it uses openssl in the version 1.0.2g. I've downloaded the latest source-code openssl-1.1.0c from the website and compiled it, which worked fined. Now I've downloaded a example code and tried to compile it, but I've got a linking error.

```
rm -f  ./cert.o
gcc    -c -o cert.o cert.c
gcc -Wall -g -fPIC -I../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl      -o cert  ./cert.o ../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/libssl.a     ../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/libcrypto.a -lpthread  -ldl
./cert.o: In Funktion `main':
cert.c:(.text+0x48d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sk_new_null'
cert.c:(.text+0x4d4): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sk_push'
cert.c:(.text+0x74e): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `sk_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:13: die Regel für Ziel „cert“ scheiterte
make: *** [cert] Fehler 1
```

Makefile:

```
appname := cert

CC := gcc
CCFLAGS := -Wall -g -fPIC -I../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl
LDLIBS := ../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/libssl.a ../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/libcrypto.a -lpthread  -ldl

srcfiles := $(shell find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.c")
objects  := $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(srcfiles))

all: clean $(appname)

$(appname): $(objects)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(appname) $(objects) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(objects)
```

So i've looked for "sk_new_null" found it in "/usr/include/openssl/stack.h".
In openssl-1.1.0c it were renamed to "OPENSSL_sk_new_null".

I think, it looks for the wrong header-files.
I'm a noob in C, how do I've change the Makefile?

Comment: Usually you use an include path which *does not* include the trailing `openssl`. I.e., use `-I../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/include`; and not `-I../../libraries/c/openssl-1.1.0c/include/openssl`. Then, in your program, you `#include <openssl/stack.h>`. Also, I expect the libraries/archives to be located at `openssl-1.1.0c/lib/libssl.a`; and not `openssl-1.1.0c/libssl.a`. But I could be wrong on both because its not clear to me where things are located in your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the wrong paths, but with almost no effect, there were also missing references. It seems that it used some of the openssl-headers in "/usr/include".

But I learned a big lesson, use "make install". I've configured openssl-1.1.0c with an prefix path to "../../libraries/c/usr". With nanomsg I did the same.

Then I add "-I../../libraries/c/usr/include" and "-L../../libraries/c/usr/lib" to the CFLAGS. It works. I can link statically and dynamically to these libraries and it use the correct header-files.

I will always install it by now to an relative path and point to it.